# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException while saving a dataframe to hdfs path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark streaming 1.6 to read messages from Tibco and I'm  performing some transformations and then trying to save it to a hdfs path.

```
receivedDf.write.format( "com.databricks.spark.avro" ).mode( SaveMode.Append ).save( inboundAvroHDFSPath )
```

The job runs fine for few batches and then I start encountering this error

```
18/12/24 04:44:39 ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File someHdfsPath/_temporary/0 does not exist.
```

After this job runs fine for next few batches and then i start receiving this error

```
18/12/24 04:44:55 ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException)
```

These error repeat for quite a few times and then the job finally aborts

```
18/12/24 05:07:30 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Here is the full stack trace of the errors received above

```
18/12/24 04:44:39 ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File someHdfsPath/_temporary/0 does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$600(DistributedFileSystem.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.dataSource$lzycompute$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameWriter$$dataSource$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$save$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.executeAndCallQEListener(DataFrameWriter.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:172)
    at com.package.MyTIBCOConsumer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(MyTIBCOConsumer.scala:149)
    at com.package.MyTIBCOConsumer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(MyTIBCOConsumer.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18/12/24 04:44:55 ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on someHdfsPath/_SUCCESS (inode 499782261): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_attempt_201812240444_0000_m_000000_0_497528331_444 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFile(FSNamesystem.java:3818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.complete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.complete(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.complete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:467)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.complete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.completeFile(DFSOutputStream.java:2835)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.completeFile(DFSOutputStream.java:2795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.closeImpl(DFSOutputStream.java:2779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.__close__(DFSOutputStream.java:2722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.dataSource$lzycompute$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameWriter$$dataSource$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$save$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.executeAndCallQEListener(DataFrameWriter.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:359)
    at com.citi.crdp.stream.CRDPTIBCOConsumer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(CRDPTIBCOConsumer.scala:143)
    at com.citi.crdp.stream.CRDPTIBCOConsumer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(CRDPTIBCOConsumer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can you help me identify the source of the problem?

Comment: I believe this bug was fixed in spark 1.3 where setting spark.speculation=false removed this error.I am using spark 1.6 and i have set this parameter to false itself still i am receiving this error

Comment: Any idea how to overcome this error?

Comment: I was using spark.streamimg.concurrentJobs=10 when I was encountering this error,upn setting this parameter to its default value doesn't lead to any _temporary file not found exception.Any idea how this concurrency is leading to this error?